# PYXB: Ignore missing attribute

Tags: python, xml, pyxb

I am parsing some XML using Pyxb and a required attribute is not available in the XML. I catch the MissingAttributeError exception which tells me:

```
Instance of <class 'TestXML.TEST.CTD_ANON_27'> lacks required attribute how
```

My question is, even though a required attribute is missing from the XML data, is there a way to still parse this XML data even though this attribute is missing? The rest of the XML data is valid and still useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [disable validation](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/api/pyxb-module.html#RequireValidWhenParsing).  Something like the following (excerpt from the test suite):

```
xmls = '<Element/>'
pyxb.RequireValidWhenParsing(True)
self.assertRaises(MissingAttributeError, CreateFromDocument, xmls)
pyxb.RequireValidWhenParsing(False)
self.assertFalse(pyxb._ParsingRequiresValid)
instance = CreateFromDocument(xmls)
```

Note that PyXB is not intended to support processing invalid documents, so the generated binding may not fully reflect the content of the XML.